# How to refer to an Academic, NGO and private partnership organization?

Tags: university, collaboration

What would you call an umbrella organization that unites a university faculty, an extra-academic non-profit research center, and a NGO?

These organizations plan to pool resources to facilitate scientific research, apply for grants, and co-publish. As there are advantages to developing a single entity to those ends, we plan to form an umbrella organization. But how to call it: a hub, a research centre, a working group… it seems there are no standard terms.

Do you guys have any experience with such entities and how they are called?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, an organization that organizes activities across multiple organizations would be called a coalition.

Comment: or consortium (and at this point one can start looking up synonyms!)

Comment: Coalition sounds like political bloc, no?

Comment: No, coalition is used for health and social services. For example, the National Coalition Against Domestic Violence.

Comment: I've seen "Partnership" used as well.